# How to Add a variable in my tweet code

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

i have made a game using html5 , now i want users to put their max scores on twitter via that tweet button , but i dont know how to put that variable max_score in my tweet code which is something like this

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I played Flying hawks and i scored : " data-count="vertical" data-via="games_html5">Tweet</a>;
```

Comment: please clarify. How is that html generated? you can use jquery / javascript to insert the score...

Comment: i declared max_score as a variable in javascript and now printing that score in html taking it as an id . <span id="max_score">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in plain old Javascript:

```
  <a id="link1" href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I played Flying hawks and i scored : " data-count="vertical" data-via="games_html5">Tweet</a>;

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var maxscore = 1000;
    var elem = document.getElementById("link1");
    elem.setAttribute("data-text", elem.getAttribute("data-text") + maxscore);
  </script>
```

(you have to fill that maxscore variable, I don't know how you set it...)

Comment: what's the error? what browser are you using? why you say it doesn't work, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what libraries you're using.  Maybe (using jQuery as an example, you have to include it in your page)

```
var twitter_btn = $('.twitter-share-button');
twitter_btn.attr('data-text', twitter_btn.attr('data_text') + max_score);
```

Comment: do we have to import jquery file min.js first ?

Comment: @Anuj, post as much of your code as you can. You may find [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) useful.